# Make a href=tel: work without adding number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript that reads a xml Phonebook, prints a table and I'd like to make each number clickable so it would launch a Phone App.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-dark" id="campanie"></table>

function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myFunction(this);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "campanie-full.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var table="<thead class=thead-light><tr><th><h5 class=text-dark>Nr.</h5></th><th><h5 class=text-dark>Company</h5></th><th><h5 class=text-dark>Phone 1</h5></th><th><h5 class=text-dark>Phone 2</h5></th></tr></thead>";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DirectoryEntry");
    for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
        table += "<tr><td><p>" +
            [i+1] + "</p></td><td><p>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</p></td><td><a href=tel:>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("Telephone")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</a></td><td><a href=tel:>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("Telephone")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</a></td></tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("campanie").innerHTML = table;
}
```

What should I do in order to have each a `href=tel:` work properly?
Also, you will see that I put the "**Telephone**" tag twice, as the Phonebook has more than one phonenumber. As a second question, I'd like to know how to make it read correctly, as the XML file can't be edited in any way. The `<Telephone>` tag from **XML** can't be changed to `<Telephone1>` or `<Telephone2>`. This question can wait, however.

EDIT: I have added an example **XML**

```
<CiscoIPPhoneDirectory>
<DirectoryEntry>
    <Name>Doctor Dolittle</Name>
    <Telephone>100</Telephone>
    <Telephone>+19001234567</Telephone>
</DirectoryEntry>
<DirectoryEntry>
    <Name>Tommy Stubbins</Name>
    <Telephone>101</Telephone>
</DirectoryEntry>
<DirectoryEntry>
    <Name>Chee-Chee</Name>
    <Telephone>102</Telephone>
</DirectoryEntry>
<DirectoryEntry>
    <Name>Prince Bumpo</Name>
    <Telephone>103</Telephone>
</DirectoryEntry>
<DirectoryEntry>
    <Name>Polynesia</Name>
    <Telephone>104</Telephone>
</DirectoryEntry>
<DirectoryEntry>
    <Name>Gub-Gub</Name>
    <Telephone>105</Telephone>
</DirectoryEntry>
<DirectoryEntry>
    <Name>Jip</Name>
    <Telephone>106</Telephone>
</DirectoryEntry>
<DirectoryEntry>
    <Name>Dab-Dab</Name>
    <Telephone>107</Telephone>
</DirectoryEntry>
```

Comment: Just append the phone number in to the `href`..? You're already concatenating it in other places, so I'm not sure where the confusion is. The output should look like `<a href="tel:0123456789">`

Comment: If I do that, it will call to 0123456789 whatever the number is.

Comment: Well, yes. That's what a `<a href="tel:...">` *is for*

Comment: Can you post a small example of one of the nodes that you're getting the data from?  We can see that you're not putting the phone number into the tag, as suggested above by Rory, but the mention of two numbers needs clarification.

Comment: Well it doesn't work then, like that. I tried making a separate function that when a class is defined like `phonenr` it will automatically make it `tel:number`, but with no avail.

Comment: You need to add `"<a href='tel:" + telephoneNumber + "'>" + telephoneNumber + "</a>"` to the html.

Comment: I have added it, I'll try it.

Comment: Is it only ever 1 or two phone numbers - never more?

Comment: Yes. 1 or 2 numbers, never more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to check the Xml to see whether there are 1 or 2 phone numbers.  (You could also make it check for none, if that could ever happen, and not add a row at all).  Then you add either the 2nd phone number or an empty cell, depending on what the data says.

Change the function that creates the table contents from the Xml response, like this...

```
function myFunction(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var table="<thead class=thead-light>" +
        "<tr><th><h5 class=text-dark>Nr.</h5></th>" +
        "<th><h5 class=text-dark>Company</h5></th>" +
        "<th><h5 class=text-dark>Phone 1</h5></th>" +
        "<th><h5 class=text-dark>Phone 2</h5></th>" +
        "</tr></thead>";

    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DirectoryEntry");

    for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
        var name = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var tel1 = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Telephone")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var tel2 = "";

        // if there are 2 phone numbers, get the value of the 2nd one
        if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("Telephone").length === 2) {
            // check that it's not an empty node...
            if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("Telephone")[1].childNodes) {
                tel2 = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Telephone")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            }
        }

        table += "<tr><td><p>" + [i+1] + "</p></td>" +
            "<td><p>" + name + "</p></td>" +
            "<td><a href='tel:" + tel1 + "'>" + tel1 + "</a></td>";

        // if we don't have a 2nd phone number then add an empty cell
        if (tel2 === "") {
            table += "<td></td>";
        }
        // if we do have a 2nd phone number then add it
        else {
            table += "<td><a href='tel:" + tel2 + "'>" + tel2 + "</a></td>";
        }

        table += "</tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("campanie").innerHTML = table;
}
```